# Is my SD card physically broken?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, sd-card, testdisk

I have a 64GB Kingston Micro SD card that I am wondering if could be physically broken since I am completely unable to repair or restore it. I have no data on it to worry about, so I only want to restore it to a state where it is usable again.

Currently, if I try to chkdsk or format (quick or normal) in Windows the disk automatically unmounts itself.

I tried creating a new partition in gparted (it shows as "Unallocated"). Gparted asks me to create a partition table, and when doing so (I went for msdos, is that ok?) it seems to hang (the gparted window goes gray). After 10 minutes and no response I kill gparted (by removing the card).

Here is some info from dmesg that might be useful: http://pastebin.com/Uj9q3xZ0

I have also tried running testdisk to analyze the disk. It freezes with the following message:

> Disk /dev/mmcblk0 - 63 GB / 59 GiB - CHS 1933824 4 16
>   Analyse cylinder  6624/1933823: 00%.

The log shows the following:

> Disk /dev/mmcblk0 - 63 GB / 59 GiB - CHS 1933824 4 16, sector size=512
>
> Partition table type default to Intel Disk /dev/mmcblk0 - 63 GB / 59
>   GiB Partition table type: Intel
>
> Analyse Disk /dev/mmcblk0 - 63 GB / 59 GiB - CHS 1933824 4 16 Current
>   partition structure:
>
> Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55

dmesg shows a bunch of the following (repeated many many times): http://pastebin.com/ZDbUzffs

I have tried this with inbuilt SD card reader in laptop, external card reader on all my USB ports and 3 different computers (1 Win7 and 2 Ubuntu).

As I said, I dont care about any old partitions or data on the disk, I just want to have a usable SD card again. Any suggestions on what to try? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Judging by you tests, I'd say you might not be able to make the SD card usable again. Try using the official [SD formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/).

Comment: You might want to just recreate the partition, have you already? Run `mkfs.ntfs /dev/mmcblk0` and show the results.

Answer (score 2):

It's dead by the looks of it. I'm afraid this isn't uncommon, memory cards do die quite regularly.

Always have a backup (it sounds like you have if you aren't worried about the contents).

Answer (score 0):

Let me add one more possibility here for future reference.

If you are using the microSD card with full-size SD adapter, the adapter may be bad. This is especially common with cheaper cards, and these adapters may go bad pretty quickly too. (In my experience as little as 10 uses in the worst case.)

The most reliable way to tell if the card is still good is to use a dedicated microSD reader, possibly a higher-quality one. A mobile phone that takes microSD card can also be used. I generally recommend using microSD readers for microSD cards.